# Continuous collision in cocos2d-x 3.0 built-in physics (chipmunk)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, physics, cocos2d-x-3.0, chipmunk

I have used cocos2d-x-3.0 built-in physics for my game.

My problem is that my physics bodies are passing through physics boundaries, around the physics world. It is observed when physics body size is small and velocity is high.

I used box2d for my past native (cocos2d-iPhone) games, there, I solved this problem by enabling isBullet property of physics bodies but here, chipmunk does not support this (continuous collision).

Is there a way to fix it? or should I leave built-in physics engine and implement box2d by my own?

Comment: For this issue, I had to leave builtin physics engine (chipmunk) and used box2d  separately.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can try to use `PhysicsWorld::setSubsteps` 
One physics update will be divided into several substeps to increase its accuracy. Or `PhysicsWorld::setUpdateRate` Set it higher can improve performance, set it lower can improve accuracy of physics world simulation. I hope this helps:)